# Overflow-safe modular addition and subtraction in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, optimization

I'm implementing an algorithm in C that needs to do modular addition and subtraction quickly on unsigned integers and can handle overflow conditions correctly. Here's what I have now (which does work):

```
/* a and/or b may be greater than m */
uint32_t modadd_32(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t m) {
    uint32_t tmp;
    if (b <= UINT32_MAX - a)
        return (a + b) % m;

    if (m <= (UINT32_MAX>>1))
        return ((a % m) + (b % m)) % m;

    tmp = a + b;
    if (tmp > (uint32_t)(m * 2)) // m*2 must be truncated before compare
        tmp -= m;
    tmp -= m;
    return tmp % m;
}

/* a and/or b may be greater than m */
uint32_t modsub_32(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t m) {
    uint32_t tmp;
    if (a >= b)
        return (a - b) % m;

    tmp = (m - ((b - a) % m)); /* results in m when 0 is needed */
    if (tmp == m)
        return 0;
    return tmp;
}
```

Anybody know of a better algorithm? The libraries I've found that do modular arithmetic all seem to be for large arbitrary precision numbers which is way overkill.

Edit: I want this to run well on a 32 bit machine. Also, my existing functions are trivially converted to work on other sizes of unsigned integers, a property which would be nice to retain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modular operations usually assume that a and b are less than m. This allows simpler algorithms:

```
umod_t sub_mod(umod_t a, umod_t b, umod_t m)
{
  if ( a>=b )
    return a - b;
  else
    return m - b + a;
}

umod_t add_mod(umod_t a, umod_t b, umod_t m)
{
  if ( 0==b ) return a;

  // return sub_mod(a, m-b, m);
  b = m - b;
  if ( a>=b )
    return a - b;
  else
    return m - b + a;
}
```

Source: [Matters Computational](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/#fxtbook), chapter 39.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to assume that a and b are less than m for this particular application.

Comment: @ryanc: you might just add `a%=m;b%=m;` at the start of each function. This still gives simpler algorithms. Are they faster or slower than algorithms in OP, depends on hardware and parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do the arithmetic in `uint32_t` if it fits and in `uint64_t` otherwise.

```
uint32_t modadd_32(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t m) {
    if (b <= UINT32_MAX - a)
        return (a + b) % m;
    else
        return ((uint64_t)a + b) % m;
}
```

On an architecture with 64bit integer types, this should be almost no overhead, you could even think of just doing everything in `uint64_t`. On architectures where `uint64_t` is synthesized 
 let the compiler decide what he thinks is best, an then look into the generated assembler and mmeasure to see if this is satisfactory.

Comment: I'm looking for something that will work well even on 32 bit, and generated assembler (at least from GCC) to handle 64 bit numbers is rather slow. Thank you though, I should have been more clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Overflow-safe modular addition

First establish that `a<m` and `b<m` with the usual `% m`.

Add updated `a` and `b`.

Should `a` (or `b`) exceed the `uintN_t` sum, then the mathematically sum was an `uintN_t` overflow and subtraction of `m` will "mod" the mathematically sum into the range of `uintN_t`.

If the sum exceeds `m`, then like the above step, a single subtraction of `m` will "mod" the sum.

```
uintN_t modadd_N(uintN_t a, uintN_t b, uintN_t m) {
  // may omit these 2 steps if a < b and a < m are known before the call.
  a %= m;
  b %= m;

  uintN_t sum = a + b;
  if (sum >= m || sum < a) {
    sum -= m;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Quite simple in the end.

---

> Overflow-safe modular subtraction

Variation on [@Evgeny Kluev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249135/2410359) good answer.

```
uintN_t modsub_N(uintN_t a, uintN_t b, uintN_t m) {
  // may omit these 2 steps if a < b and a < m are known before the call.
  a %= m;
  b %= m;

  uintN_t diff = a - b;  
  if (a < b) {
    diff += m;
  }
  return diff;
}
```

---

Note this approach works for various `N` such as `32, 64, 16` or `unsigned`, `unsigned long`, etc.  without resorting to wider types.  It also works for unsigned types narrower than `int/unsigned`.